# Installing Win patches with Powershell, the script runs, but nothing installs

Tags: powershell

I'm no expert in PowerShell by any means, but I am learning. I've created this code to install MSP and MSU files, but nothing installs.

```
$p=Start-Process -FilePath wusa.exe -ArgumentList "$($f.FullName) /quiet /norestart" -PassThru -wait
```

Comment: You don't need `Start-Process`. Just type the command you want to run and press `Enter`.

Comment: You might have to do this from an elevated prompt as well.

Comment: Cleared up the question and put the code in a code section

Answer (score -1):

Try invoke-expression, something like:

```
invoke-expression "& 'wusa.exe' '[path to patch]' '/quiet /norestart'"
```

Is wusa.exe the proper thing to use here? I think most patches end up as .msi (or .cab?) files so you could just invoke those with windows installer, although not explicitly saying what program to open with will just result in it opening with whatever the system default is, if you're feeling risky, that is.

Comment: You don't need `Invoke-Expression` to do that. Just type `wusa "path to patch" /quiet /norestart` and press `Enter`. PowerShell is a shell. You can type commands and press `Enter` to run them, just like you can in cmd.exe.

Comment: Well aware that you can do everything you can do in command prompt, but can you explain why we wouldn't want to use invoke-expression here? I've seen similar situations and don't quite understand why we couldn't just use that

Comment: `Invoke-Expression`, in this example, accomplishes nothing except making the command harder to read.

Comment: Okay, understood but why does it exist if we can use things like command line and start-process for example?

Comment: I recommend not using `Invoke-Expression` except in very rare cases because it is susceptible to [command injection](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png). Avoid it in this case, particularly when you don't need it.